# JSF Custom component? How to add Method expression support?

Tags: java, jsf-2, custom-component

i want  add Method Expression support on to my custom component.
i've seen that i must write a tagHandler.

i've seen this post : 
[How to add Method Expression to a custom JSF component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144319/how-to-add-method-expression-to-a-custom-jsf-component)

I don't understand what are the parameters "void.class" and "moveEvent" of the methodRule method.

This is my customComponent code :

```
public class Link extends UIOutput{

private StringBuilder style = new StringBuilder();
private String id = "";
private Boolean active = false;
private String alt = "";
private String href = "";
private String hreflang = "";
private String rel = "";
private String target = "";
private String download = "";
private String media = "";
private String type = "";


public Boolean isActive() {
    return active;
}

public void setActive(Boolean active) {
    this.active = active;
}

public String getAlt() {
    return alt;
}

public void setAlt(String alt) {
    this.alt = alt;
}

public String getHref() {
    return href;
}

public void setHref(String href) {
    this.href = href;
}

public String getHreflang() {
    return hreflang;
}

public void setHreflang(String hreflang) {
    this.hreflang = hreflang;
}

public String getRel() {
    return rel;
}

public void setRel(String rel) {
    this.rel = rel;
}

public String getTarget() {
    return target;
}

public void setTarget(String target) {
    this.target = target;
}

public String getDownload() {
    return download;
}

public void setDownload(String download) {
    this.download = download;
}

public String getMedia() {
    return media;
}

public void setMedia(String media) {
    this.media = media;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}



@Override
public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context)throws IOException {
    ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
    String clientId = getClientId(context);
    if("".equals(id) || id == null){
        id = clientId;
    }
    Object styleClass = (getAttributes().get("styleClass") != null) ? (Boolean)getAttributes().get("styleClass") : "";
    writer.startElement("li", this);
    if(active){
        style.append(" active ");
    }
    if(!"".equals(styleClass)){
        style.append(styleClass);
    }
    writer.writeAttribute("id", id, null);

    writer.writeAttribute("class", style.toString().trim(), null);
    writer.startElement("a", this);
    writer.writeAttribute("href", href, null);
    if(!"".equals(alt)) { writer.writeAttribute("alt", alt, null); }
    if(!"".equals(hreflang)) { writer.writeAttribute("hreflang", hreflang, null); }
    System.out.println("rel = " + rel);
    if(!"".equals(rel)) { writer.writeAttribute("rel", rel, null); }
    if(!"".equals(target)) {  writer.writeAttribute("target", target, null); }
    if(!"".equals(download)) {  writer.writeAttribute("download", download, null); }
    if(!"".equals(media)) {  writer.writeAttribute("media", media, null); }
    if(!"".equals(type)) {  writer.writeAttribute("type", type, null); }
    for (UIComponent child : getChildren()) {
        child.encodeAll(context);
    }
}

@Override
public Object saveState(FacesContext context) {
    Object values[] = new Object[10];
    values[0] = super.saveState(context);
    values[1] = id;
    values[2] = style;
    values[3] = active;
    values[4] = alt;
    values[5] = href;
    values[6] = hreflang;
    values[7] = rel;
    values[8] = target;
    values[9] = download;
    values[10] = media;
    values[110] = type;
    return ((Object) (values));
}

@Override
public void restoreState(FacesContext context, Object state) {
    Object values[] = (Object[])state;
    super.restoreState(context, values[0]);
    id = (String)values[1];
    style.insert(0, values[2]);
    active = (Boolean)values[3];
    alt = (String)values[4];
    href = (String)values[5];
    hreflang = (String)values[6];
    rel = (String)values[7];
    target = (String)values[8];
    download = (String)values[9];
    media = (String)values[10];
    type = (String)values[11];
}
```

}

Comment: It's easier to just let your component extend from `UICommand`.

Comment: uhmm, my component extends from UIOutput and nothing append. i have nullPointerException.

Comment: Yes, I know. I just commented that it's easier to let your component extend from `UICommand`. Then you've support for `action`, `actionListener` and friends readily available without messing with tag handlers and, importantingly, also without the need to manually write all the component code necessary for action event decoding/queueing/broadcasting. But this all of course depends on the concrete functional requirement of the custom component in question, which you didn't tell anything about (and therefore it's not possible to give "the best" answer).

Comment: Ok, i write a set of composant. So i will write lot of types (UIOuput, UIInput, etc...). I need to know how i can make tag Handlers.

Comment: It's not necessary if you just extend from the right component superclass, such as `UICommand` for an action component.

Comment: I post my CustomComponent that extend form UIOutput

Comment: You seem to want to create an extension to `<h:commandLink>`. In that case, it's yet more easier to extend from `HtmlCommandLink` instead so that you only need to define the new attributes instead of redefining all existing attributes. You namely seem to merely want to add some custom attribtues like `download` and `media` on top of `<h:commandLink>`. Is that true? Or is there more that you need to extend on the `<h:commandLink>`? By the way, that save/restore state code is JSF 1.2 style and can be done yet more simpler for JSF 2.x (you don't need those methods at all!).

Comment: This component is just a basic example and first try. I want to make common components like table, navbar, etc... compatibles with one css framework. So i need to be able to build all parts of custom components.